# "EnsureDatabase" fails the first time with: "Database not found on server with connection string in settings"

Tags: .net, sql-server, database-migration, dbup

I am trying to use DbUp to set up migration scripts for my Database.
Problem is whenever I use:

```
var connectionString = configuration.GetSection("DbSetting").Get<DbSettings>().ConnectionString;
EnsureDatabase.For.SqlDatabase(connectionString);
```

The **EnsureDatabase** fails with the error:

> Database not found on server with connection string in settings: Cannot open database "TvMazeScraperDB" requested by the login. The login failed.

Point is Db is not yet existing and that's why I am running the **EnsureDatabase** in such a way that it gets created! Any solution by any chance? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: weird thing I notice is that if I go step by step through debugging, everything works well. But if I run the application instead the problem appears:

[image]

Comment: You can't connect to a database that doesn't exist. If you know it doesn't exist, don't try connecting to it.

Comment: @Larnu "Created database..." the EnsureDatabase creates it

Comment: Experiencing same. I opened up a Github issue: https://github.com/DbUp/DbUp/issues/489

Comment: @derekbaker783 that's great man! In the meantime I tell you who I resolved it: downgrade to previous version and the problem is not there anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem happens with 4.3.0 release. Downgrade to 4.0.0 and it won't happen anymore (as a temporary fix till a stable one)

Answer (score -1):

We also need to set authentication to trust in C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\data\pg_hba.conf - view details

[image]